# Android: Set layout as background of view

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to set another layout as the background for a view?

What I'm looking to do is have a text view that performs a countdown behind my grid view.

I've tried setting my layout as background resource for my grid view but it seems to expect a drawable only.

What is best workaround for this? How would I go about stacking this layout behind the grid view possibly with a transparent background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FrameLayout can be used to stack things on top of other things.

Here is an example where I combined the [HelloGridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) code and my own layout of text views (that tries to emulate your counter). The result is a that the GridView displays dog pictures with the counter TextViews sort of floating above.

Hope this helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/counterLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counterLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Counter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counterValue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="128"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```